# If data exist in database

Tags: php, sql

I trying to check in my database if a customer with the same postcode exist already in the customer table and if they do.

I have the PHP code below and the issue I am having is that. I already get the echo message, weather the exist or they don't exist. `select_to_array` is a function in the `config.php` and it works fine.

```
<?php
require("config.php");

    $validate_value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : null; 
    $validate_Year =isset($_POST['Year']) ? $_POST['value'] : null; 
    $validate_postcode  = isset($_POST['postcode']) ? $_POST['value'] : null; 
    $select = "SELECT count (*) FROM customers WHERE reg_year= :reg_year 
                 AND reg_code = :reg_name AND reg_value = :reg_value";

                $bind_bb = array(':reg_year' => $validate_Year,
                                    ':reg_code' => $validate_code,
                                    ':reg_value' => $validate_value);


                $validate_result = select_to_array($db_connect,$select, $index, $bind_bb);


        if ($validate_result[0][0] == 0) {  

        echo 'Customer Does not no exist';

        }       
        else {

        echo 'Already exist, please try a different postcode';

        }       
?>
```

Comment: Umm where's `$validate_name` set? also check the values in the ternary's?

Comment: Try using `if($validate_result->rowCount() > 0){ echo "Exists"; } else{ echo "Does not exist";} ` see if that works. I think that is a better approach to first check if it exists and echo "success", and if it does not exist "after".

Comment: and if that doesn't work, try `if($select->rowCount() > 0)`

Comment: Thanks to the person that dislike this question.

Comment: You're welcome, in regards to my comment of course, cheers. @PHPnoob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check is incorrect from many points - first you need to know if there's any data, not how much records you have, therefore your `SELECT` should feature `LIMIT 1` as this is pretty much sufficient. As for

```
if ($validate_result[0][0] == 0) {
```

this is not valid too, as if your dataset is empty you will be throwing notices. Replace with

```
if (empty($validate_result)) {
```

or

```
if (count($validate_result) == 0) {
```

also it looks you may have wrong query as this:

```
':reg_name' => $validate_name,
```

may look for empty `reg_name` as `$validate_name` is not set in your code (while other params are)

Comment: `is_empty` is undefined. that's the error i keep getting. will `empty` work the same way?

Comment: Yep, I meant `empty()`. Sorry

Comment: I did the limit 1 and i have try both  `if` but i still get `Customer Does not no exist` even thought i have enter a different `postcode` but the same `value` and `year`. Any ideas please

Comment: @PHPnoob See my comments under your original question.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it works now thanks... The person that word all the function for bind variables did a few things wrong and I have to rewrite it again bu this works now thanks